# Anaconda installation - Jupyter notebook not working

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I've installed Anaconda3 on Windows. I can run ipython in the command line (so I have it installed - v5.3.0) but when I run jupyter notebook I do not have the option to create a new notebook.

When running jupyter notebook from the command line I get the message

> 0 active kernels

Thoughts ?

[command line output when opening Jupyter notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKrXS.png)

[Screen shot of Jupyter - no Python3 option shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbkHA.png)

Comment: You get this message when you type `jupyter notebook` verbatim in the command line, yes?

Comment: it launches the notebook in internet explorer, this is part of the message in the command line. In the notebook I cannot open a new Python notebook - the option is not available

Comment: Mind posting a SS of what you see when notebook launches?

Comment: @AdamHughes - I've added an image link above showing the command line output

Comment: Ah sorry, I meant of your web browser where you can't open a new notebook.

Comment: @AdamHughes I've added a screen shot above.